# Chrome extension: after React `npm run build` error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension and a completely separate web-page which I wrote in React. I can no problem use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and it works perfectly. I'm also using /*global chrome*/

However, once I do `npm run build` and then deploy this onto IIS, then I have this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined`!

So how can I have `chrome.runtime` accessible *after* the `npm run build`?

Comment: For a web page to have access to chrome.runtime.sendMessage, your extension should declare externally_connectable and use onMessageExternal, [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Yes, did all that: it works from ‘src’ react folder, but once I deploy after ‘npm build’ it generates this error. Should I change the settings of  ‘npm build’?

Comment: It probably means externally_connectable is incorrect because Chrome exposes `chrome.runtime` only when the web page has at least one external extension listener.

Comment: Yes! I am indeed was wrong there: the port made all the difference. Thank you!

Comment: So, we would encounter an error if there is no extension installed with an 'externally_connectable' match for the URL? I encountered this problem when I tried to open the webapp from the same machine but with <IP Addr> URL rather than localhost URL.